# Libssh2: prevent background task from being killed

Tags: c++, c, linux, libssh2, libssh

I am writing a program that logs into another system via SSH using the *libssh2* library. Once logged in, I execute a command using:

```
libssh2_channel_exec(sshchannel, command)
```

The command executes okay. However, once I close the channel the process running is killed. In my case, the command (executing a binary executable) will run for a long period of time and my program cannot wait for it to terminate. I've tried issuing the following commands all to the same result (the process is still killed upon closing the channel):

```
/path/myprog
nohup /path/myprog
nohup /path/myprog &
/path/myprog &; disown
```

Further, I've observed this behavior for both *libssh* and *libssh2*. Is there some option or command I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the unix `at` command:

```
echo "cmd" | at now
```